# Is there a way to simulate Photoshop's 'fill' functionality in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, vector, transparency, fill, file-placing

Photoshop has two distinct opacity values for any layer: 'Opacity' and 'Fill'; the former affects the entire layer and all its effects, the latter only affects the layer content and not the effects.

I find myself wanting to reproduce this effect in InDesign. I have a vector file placed with a transparent background and added a drop shadow effect to it. Is it possible to hide the actual file's contents but keep the drop shadow visible?

Comment: Does the EPS file contain vector or raster graphics?  How is it consturcted? Have you tried opening it in Adobe Illustrator to see?

Comment: @BillyKerr The .eps is irrelevant. It was just an example, I updated the question accordingly. Please suppose it's vector and I made it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably expected, no such feature in Indesign.
However, you can simulate the effect by:

- applying a huge [paper] inner glow. Normal mode, 100%. This will turn your artwork into white
- applying your drop shadow. Make sure the option 'Object Knocks Out Shadow' is *unticked*.
- setting object transparency to multiply. Now let the magic happen:

[image]

NB: Don't forget you can create an *Object style* in order to reapply the effect in a fast and easy way.

Comment: This is the workaround I was looking for. Awesome! I went ahead and added the cave canem that the drop shadow's settings should include the object *not* knocking out the shadow in order for it to work.

Comment: @Vincent glad I could help. About "Object not knocking out", it depends on what you want to achieve really... I apparently got it wrong, so let me redo the gif. Also, the good think with not knocking is that it allows you to pick any king of blending, you don't have to stick to multiply. (So I'll edit that too)

Answer (score 4):

This is InDesign CS6. So, it's feasible there's a difference in newer CC versions...

## inDesign effects applied to placed graphics

If the effect, such as drop shadow, is **applied in InDesign** to a placed graphic, it **is** possible to adjust the graphic opacity **separate** from the effect opacity.

Merely use the **Direct Selection Tool** (White arrow) to select the *contents* within a frame and adjust its opacity. You'll note on the **Effect Panel** the item description changes to "Graphic" rather than "object". (You can tell the difference in selection within the animation below by the highlight colors -- green = Frame selected, Violet = Contents selected.)

Here the red shadow is an InDesign Effect. I select the *contents* of the frame and then adjust the "*graphic*" opacity as opposed to the "object" opacity.

[image]

For some effects, such as a drop shadow, you will probably need to boost the `Spread` setting a little. Without an increase in the `Spread` the shadow can disappear when the graphic's opacity falls below a certain level.

---

## Internal effects within placed graphics

If one plans ahead, it's feasible to use InDesign's **Object Layer Options** (Object menu with placed graphic selected).

You can construct a file with things such as a drop shadow applied to its own layer. Then simply turn off visibility of other layers and adjust the blending mode in InDesign.

- 3 layer AI file placed into InDesign CS6
- `Object > Object Layer Options...` chosen from the menu....
- The blue is a simple cyan-filled frame in InDesign.

[image]

With this in mind, you *can* structure an InDesign file with a duplicate of the graphic to allow separate opacity adjustments...

- Place the graphic
- `Edit > Copy`
- `Edit > Deselect All`
- `Edit > Paste in Place`

This provides 2 copies of the same placed object which are positioned in the *exact* same location.

I've used InDesign layers here for clarity (You can Paste in Place to a new Layer if desired). You don't *have* to use layers in InDesign. Simple stacking of duplicate graphics works the same.

Each copy or iteration of the placed graphic merely has different `Object Layer Options` set -- One to **show** *only* the shadow, and one to **hide** *only* the shadow.

[image]

It **does** take some layer structure planning in the EPS/AI file and it's nowhere near as simple as Photoshop's Fill Opacity. But this *might* help in some circumstances. I think this is as close as you'll get with InDesign.

---

Comment: Even though I ticked Vinny's answer as the correct one, that being exactly and succinctly the workflow I was looking for, this answer taught me a lot more than I'd expected. Thanks, Scott, for pointing me to two features I didn't know existed to start playing around with!

Comment: Whatever works @Vincent `:)` That's the important thing `:)`

Comment: (and I still work in CS6 too, so that's actually a perfect fit :))